# Query to join tables, void duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've tried searching around to no avail so hopefully you'll be able to help here. I've been struggling with this for a few days now. The data is in MS Access if that helps in answers. If this isn't the right program to use for this suggestions on how to proceed are very much welcome.

Im starting with tables 1 and 2, and want to end up with table 3 (as below).

Field2(table1) and Field4(table2) are the same values (identical). However, because they have 2 identical values (i.e. 1000) when i try to do a join it makes too many duplicates. I basically want in the final table for Field 1 to only be present once (no duplicates) and the first time it calls a value from Field 3 to not duplicate that value (Identical values may be present but they will have different Field4s associated with them).

Table 2 has many more values than exist in table 1 and some need to be skipped over (i.e. the value 1002 in Table2 doesn't have a matching "L" value in Table1 and so can be ignored). An example of the results I dont want is shown in table 4 for reference purposes. Table 1 may have some "L" values which aren't in table 2 but I would still like those returned with either a blank or a cell filled with N/A...

Many thanks!

Table1

```
Field1  Field2
L1      1000
L2      1000
L3      1001
L4      1003
L5      1005
```

Table 2

```
Field3  Field4  Field5  Primary Key
4.5     1000    2000    1
3.4     1000    2000    2
2.4     1001    2001    3
1.7     1002    2002    4
1.4     1003    2003    5
```

Table 3 - The results I want

```
Field1  Field2  Field3  Field5
L1      1000    4.5   2000
L2      1000    3.4   2000
L3      1001    2.4   2001
L4      1003    1.4   2003
L5      1005    NA      NA
```

Table4-The results I don't want where L1 and L2 become duplicated.

```
Field1  Field2  Field3  Field5
L1      1000    4.5   2000
L1      1000    3.4   2000
L2      1000    4.5   2000
L2      1000    3.4   2000
L3      1001    2.4   2001
L4      1003    1.4   2003
```

Comment: What field in table 2 does field 1 in table 1 relate to? Seems like you are missing a value by which to filter out unwanted "L" values from table 2 based on your sample data set. Can you post the SQL you are using to get the unwanted result (table4)?

Comment: As you already noted, when 2 rows from one table match 2 rows from another, there are 4 possible resulting rows and the DBMS will return all of them by default. What criteria do you wish to use to decide which one of these rows should be kept?

Comment: @jn29098 Sorry, I don't have it in front of me right now but can update tomorrow. Field 2 relates to Field 4. They have matching values.

Comment: @Branko, I wish to keep the one with the largest value first (though truth be told this doesn't matter - it could be the smallest). The important par is that once the assigned value has been assigned an L value to not assign that again. i.e. as in L1 should only become 4.5 and L2 become 3.4 (the other value found at Field2 position 1000). I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @losty cant you do a left join and then group by `Field1` and `Field2`?

Comment: Does Field1 table2 relate to primary key table1 except for the L? If not, it is beginning to look like you will have to use VBA rather than SQL.

Comment: @nawfal, I think I've tried this but will try again.

Comment: @Remou I think I know what you mean, and the answer I belive is no, there aren't any other relationships unfortunately. If you can provide any help with VBA code for access that'd be great.

Comment: You could add a field to table1 to be updated with primary key match from table2. Straight sql will do for rows where there is only one match, after that, loop through the table and update with primary key where not exists primary key in table1 newfield.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's not possible to answer your question using just plain SQL. But you could use some VBA to extract just the rows that you need:

```
Sub ExtractNoDuplicates()
  Dim Rs As Recordset
  Dim precField1 As Variant
  Dim precField2 As Variant
  Dim precID As Variant

  precField1 = Null
  precField2 = Null
  precID = Null

  Set Rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * from Table1 left join Table2 on table1.Field2 = table2.Field4 order by Field2, Field1, ID")

  While Not Rs.EOF
    If (IsNull(precID) Or IsNull(precField1))
       Or (precField1 <> Rs("Field1") And Rs("ID") > precID)
       Or (precField2 <> Rs("Field2")) Then

      precField1 = Rs("Field1")
      precField2 = Rs("Field2")
      precID = Rs("ID")
      ' print the row - or add it to a temporary table
      Debug.Print Rs("Field1"), Rs("Field2"), Rs("Field3"), Rs("Field5"), Rs("id")
      End If
    Rs.MoveNext
  Wend

  Rs.Close
  Set Rs = Nothing

End Sub
```